# Regex Only Match First Url Part Without Dash

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I need to match the first url part below, without taking into account any other url parts after it.

This

```
^/events/(?<action>.*?)(?:table)?/(?<eventid>\d*)$
```

works fine for

```
/events/scheduletable/39
```

but I want to skip this

```
/events/divisions/documents/teams/127
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `.*` before `$` to avoid matching not-needed URIs

```
^/events/(?<action>[^/]*)/(?<eventid>\d*)$
```

Comment: Its still matching both strings